# GeoIP & fopen() - "fopen(GeoIP/GeoIP.dat) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream" occurs even though file is there?

Tags: php, include, fopen, geoip

I've been trying to debug this error for over three hours now, changing filenames, trying to use GeoIP Lite instead of GeoCity (the latter has a 27mb file to be included, so did this thinking `fopen()` had a max), etc.

Here's my structure file structure: `index.php -> include("configuration/config.php") - config.php -> include("inc/geo_text.php") -> geo_text.php`

The contents of `geo_text.php` is:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
include("GeoIP/geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$count_name = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $ip);
geoip_close($gi);

echo($count_name);
```

Now, if I access `geo_text.php` no errors are given, and just to make sure I placed `echo($count_name)` in `geo_text.php` and it returned, as it should, my country.

However, when I run `config.php` it returns the error:

`Warning: fopen(GeoIP/GeoIP.dat) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c09/h02/mnt/177978/domains/domain.com/html/labs/final/configuration/inc/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 399
Can not open GeoIP/GeoIP.dat`

Has anyone got any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a path issue.

> geoip_open("/absolute/path/to/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

should work.

Comment: It appears to be looking for it in /nfs/c09/h02/mnt/177978/domains/domain.com/html/labs/final/configuration/inc/GeoIP/GeoIP/geoip.inc, since geoip.inc is already in GeoIP dir you may just need to change it to ("GeoIP.dat") instead.

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesn't work :(. Also, it wouldn't explain why `geo_text.php` would work, but `config.php` wouldn't. I'm thinking it must be something to do with the inclusion of files, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Ah, it's because I wasn't using the absolute path, but it still doesn't explain why `geo_text.php` would work, and others wouldn't. When file A is included into file B which in turn is included into file C, does it attempt to resolve file A to file C through the path of file B, i.e. if file B includes `C/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat` and file A  includes file B, does it also look for `C/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat` instead of `B/C/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat` or something?

Comment: Because config.php is not in the same directory as geo_text.php I am guessing.  As a last resort, you could always do something like: error_log("Operating relative of script " . PHP_SELF . " in directory " . realpath(_\_FILE_\_)); 
Add that to the top of the script in question and watch your error log, it will give you an idea of the path situation.  The fact you have 2 GeoIP dirs (one inside the other) is probably what is confusing you, as config lives in GeoIP and geo_text probably lives in GeoIP/GeoIP.

Comment: Easier than using the full absolute path is the use dirname to let php figure it out. geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__).'"/geoip/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

Answer (score 2):

SSH into your server and run the following command (assuming it's a Linux server):

```
cd /nfs/c09/h02/mnt/177978/domains/domain.com/html/labs/final/configuration/inc/GeoIP/
ls -lah
```

Then paste the output here for us to see. My guess is that that path doesn't exist.

---

That's very strange. As a test, try moving both geo files into the same directory as your code files and then alter the paths in your code accordingly.

---

It's checking for the files in domain.com, but you just cd'd into themeplated.com, that's the problem. Your code needs to point to the themeplated.com directory.

/nfs/c09/h02/mnt/177978/domains/**domain.com**/html/labs/final/configuration/inc/GeoIP/
/nfs/c09/h02/mnt/127878/domains/**themeplated.com**/html/labs/final/c‌​onfiguration/inc/GeoIP/

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I've never used SSH before: domain.com@n11:/nfs/c09/h02/mnt/127878/domains/themeplated.com/html/labs/final/configuration/inc/GeoIP$ ls -lah
total 953K
drwxr-xr-x 2 domain.com domain.com    5 2011-08-13 15:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 domain.com domain.com    6 2011-08-13 15:42 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 domain.com domain.com 1.2M 2011-08-13 15:11 GeoIP.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 domain.com domain.com  31K 2011-08-13 15:10 geoip.inc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 domain.com domain.com   41 2011-08-13 15:23 var_dump.php

Comment: The path you cd'd into has themeplated.com in it but the code above is looking for the file under domain.com, which is what the problem is.

Comment: It was a placeholder, I didn't directly copy and paste :(.

Comment: Then please do copy and paste everything you have previously manually typed. Manually typing error messages just increases the chance that you will duplicate a path error you made in your code.

Comment: I figured the issue out, I had no idea that some files required absolute paths, and others only relative, so I was using a relative path, which messed things up when the file was included. Thanks very much for your input and help though :). If you're not too busy, is there any chance you could explain why it could occur, or link me to a reference if you've got one as I haven't managed to find one? Also I take it I should make a habit out of using absolute paths in the future or is there a way of determining if a file needs an absolute path?

Comment: A relative path works fine as long as you have the relative path correct. Telling you to use an absolute path just rules one more thing out.